# strange behavior of php in implicit convert

Tags: php

strangely the following code return true!

```
 if ('1'==1 && '014'==016)
    echo 1;
```

and output is

```
  1
```

can anyone tell me why '014' is equal to 016? and how to solve this problem? and if it is possible avoid to do a explicit convert because the data type all the time is vary.

i'm using PHP Version 5.3.8-ZS5.5.0

Comment: You have `===` for this

Comment: Hi Mo Hrad A, Hope my comment will help you...

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky : the `===` always return false even in `if ('014'===014)`

Comment: That is what it is supposed to do. A String `014` is not equal to number `014`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PHP, using an integer value with a leading zero leads PHP to assume it's an octal number. Octal 016 is equal to decimal 14.

Using a string such as `'014'` is implicitly cast to a decimal `14` when used in a comparison with another integer.

See http://php.net/manual/language.types.integer.php

Comment: @phil it's so helpful, tnx

Answer (score 0):

you need to convert string values to integer first, like this:

```
        if(intval('1')==1 && intval('014')==16)
        echo 1;
```

see [intval()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
<?php

if (ltrim((int)'1',0) == ltrim(1,0) && ltrim((int)'014',0)== ltrim('016', '0'))
     echo 1;
```